# form detects inputs in real time

Tags: javascript

guys I'm new here and it's my first time posting . been learning html / CSS / javascript since 5 months ago and now I'm trying to build a very simple contact form where if there's no value it will show error icon + message error blow the input , been trying to figure it out for like 12h+ but nothing i saw in stack worked ....... already have the solution of a guy , he used javascript to manipulate the style and add and remove the error using css , but i want to do it the other way around with manipulating the DOM with JAVA using document.query Selector

```js
let  firstname  = document.querySelector("#inputfirst").value;
let form = document.querySelector('#loginform')

//form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
//    e.preventDefault();})


function validation() {
   if (firstname == "" || firstname == null || firstname == " ") {
      document.querySelector("#inputfirst").classList.add("firstname")
      document.querySelector("#firstname_Error").innerHTML = "firstname"
      return false;
   } 
   else  {
      document.querySelector("#inputfirst").classList.remove("firstname")
document.querySelector("#firstname_Error").innerHTML = ""
   }
}

/**testing for 1st input only **/
```

```css
.firstname {
  background-image: url(./images/icon-error.svg);
  background-position: 24rem 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid rgb(247, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<form novalidate id="loginform" name="loginform" onsubmit="return validation()"; >
<input id="inputfirst" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="button-shap"  required >
<span id="firstname_Error"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: you know that javascript (not java) is the only language that works in the browser? (i dont count web assembly)

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of the element inside the function.
Everything else seems to be working.
Here is the edited code.

```
let  firstnameElement  = document.querySelector("#inputfirst");
let form = document.querySelector('#loginform')

//form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
//    e.preventDefault();})


function validation() {
  let firstname = firstnameElement.value
   if (firstname == "" || firstname == null || firstname == " ") {
      document.querySelector("#inputfirst").classList.add("firstname")
      document.querySelector("#firstname_Error").innerHTML = "firstname"
      return false;
   } 
   else  {
      document.querySelector("#inputfirst").classList.remove("firstname")
      document.querySelector("#firstname_Error").innerHTML = ""
   }
}
```

Also if your javascript file is linked at the head of the html make sure to add the defer attribute so it loads after the document.

```
<script src="test.js" defer></script>
```